# Zencoder Status URL

Tags: jquery, json, zencoder

I'm working with zencoder to write a video conversion application. I got the conversion part set up just fine but I'm stumped on how to view the status of the output as its being processed. The status of the output is stored in this URL:

https://app.zencoder.com/api/v2/outputs/ + jobID + /progress.json?api_key=mysecretcode

but in order to access it dynamically, you have to retrieve the jobID. It appears to me right now as a unique random number zencoder assigns to the output. Does anyone know how I can get the jobID after I have created the job in php?. Any help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you submit your job creation request you will get a response from Zencoder that includes the job ID as well as IDs for any outputs. If you're using the [Zencoder PHP libray](https://github.com/zencoder/zencoder-php) then check out the example in the README, specifically:

```
echo "Job ID: ".$encoding_job->id."\n";
```

That job ID is what you need to call back for progress.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. That's exactly what I used. Much appreciated sir chriswarren